# Check for true or false with AddFieldToFilter method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection

I want to get the records from database where 'isDefault' returns True.

```
$project  = $this->modelProject->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(
'isDefault',
 ['eq' => true]
);
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$project  = $this->modelProject->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(
'isDefault',
 ['eq' => 1]
);
```

Also your field in the db table called isDefault?or is_default? Has to be like in the db table.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried changing true by 1 and I checked the field name but I still got an error. Thanks anyway

Comment: @AyoubElHayat What is the type of field isDefault? You can try with ['neq' => 'NULL'] or ['neq' => 0]

Comment: the type is boolean . I changed the column type to integer and I used the same syntax that you gave me. it's not perfect but it's working haha. (y) Thanks bro